# Как найти текст внутри сессии GNU Screen?

Tags: linux, bash, администрирование, grep, gnu-screen

У меня есть прога запущенная внутри сессии GNU Screen в выхлопе которой мне нужно найти кусок текста. Как это сделать?

Т.е. нужно что-то типа `screen -x --quiet | grep text4search && echo НАЙДЕНО!`.

Comment: обязательно в пакетном режиме или можно в интерактивном?

Comment: В интерактивном я могу и сам нажать.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, нашёл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается есть `screendump` и работает ровно так как я хотел:

`sudo screendump | grep 'Unable to find target partition' && echo ALARM!!!`